# individual role permission rather than automatic selected

Tags: users

I have used that module but can't remember the name & can't find it anywhere.

Suppose I have 4 roles in the site:
Anonymous user
authenticated user
Elite user
administrator

As you know, Drupal automatically permit all created roles more than authenticated role user.

If I give permission to skip comment approval to authenticate users, then it automatically allow elite users to skip comments approval.

but for my site, I have a field that I want authenticated user to edit, but no the elite user. As this field data will actually will make the user an elite member, so I can't let them change this in the future.

How can I check the box each role permission manually?

Comment: Just create an axtra role "basic member"?

Comment: thanks for reply, but new role automatically inherit permissions from authenticated role :(

Comment: Well somehow I achieved this, not the real solution though.

What I did is- installed 'registration role' & assign a new role to for registered users rather than authenticated role. Now, this role is free to edit & other role won't inherit permissions from this role. If anyone need to achieve this, I can explain more. Thanks